# Compartilhar link de App com WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

Bom dia !
   Como faço para compartilhar um link do meu app com um contato no whatsapp ? Pesquisando na internet consegui formar esse código(ele está sem testes de sucesso por que ainda estou apenas testando ele) que ao fazer a gravação de uma atividade no firebase eu abro uma biblioteca cheia de apps para poder compartilhar um link, mas até o momento eu só consigo compartilhar o texto: "O usuário x criou uma nova atividade, o que eu gostaria é que essa mensagem tivesse um link que direcionasse a pessoa direto para o perfil ou para qualquer tela do meu app por exemplo.
Segue código (do fragment da Activity) que faz o compartilhamento do texto citado acima:

```
public void compartilharAtividade(){

    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    //Uri mainUri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Teste de compartilhamento APP");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "O usuario "+ nomeUsuario + " criou uma nova atividade! Teste de Link: "+ branch);
    //share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.ramattecgmail.rafah.studying");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Teste de compartilhamento"));

}
```

na Activity principal eu chamo o branch desta forma:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchUniversalReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject, LinkProperties linkProperties, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...
            } else {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

Resumindo, eu preciso que o meu app enviei a uri dele mesmo, ou pelo menos recuperar essa Uri que eu não consigo nem fazendo na Main Activity...
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você tem algum link em específico ?

Comment: Na verdade não exatamente, é a primeira  vez que estou mexendo com compartilhamento assim, por isso posso me equivocar em algumas coisas, mas penso que ele deve funcionar da seguinte maneira: envio uma mensagem para a pessoa com um link que quando ela clicar direcionará para o app na activity perfil que carregará os dados do usuário que eu passar na mensagem, ou nesse caso com um link da atividade que foi aberta... resumidamente, ao clicar no link da mensagem ele abra o meu app.

Comment: se você mandar um link ele irá redirecionar para uma página web, não para o seu app

Comment: Então como faço para direciona-lo para o meu app ? É possivel ?

Comment: Possível é, vai ter um trabalhozinho hehe, vou fazer uma rapida pesquisa e já volto pra lhe ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom você terá que criar um deep link e adicionar no manifest da sua activity, por exemplo:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data
    android:host="www.seusite.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/home"
    android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Onde está o host, você irá adicionar a sua URL, para redirecionar para o seu link do app, mas antes de tudo não es esqueça de adicionar android-app://yourpackage name/http/www.seusite.com/home/ para que o mesmo reconhece o package do seu app.

Este link concerteza irá lhe ajduar a entender um pouco mais sobre deep link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuWQUAi7d9I

Comment: Muito obrigado Matheus, já me serviu como um norte estudar sobre deep links, mas agora, como eu faço para compartilhar esse link via mensagem do whatsapp como um putExtra da intent? Quero compartilhar esse host criado com whattsApp

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja correta não deixe de marcar como correta =) haha.. Ok só um minuto to meio garrado aqui mas jaja volto pra te ajudar

Comment: Faz o seguinte amigo, cria um botão e no click desse botão você chama seu método compartilharAtividade, quando você clicar no botão irá aparecer todos os app que você pode compartilhar que estão instalados no seu dispositivo, após isso é só clicar no aplicativo desejado ae no putextra você põe seu package/http://www.seusite.com/home

Comment: Matheus, sedei sobrgui seus conselhos e estue banch.io porém a minha pergunta ainda não foi claramente respondida, fiz varios testes mas ainda não consigo enviar a uri do meu app para um contato do whatts aonde ele click e seja direcionado para meu app.